# KafkaStreams failing to pull messages from Kafka topic when there are more than 50000 messages

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have been trying very hard from last 2 weeks to get this issue resolved but no luck yet.

I have 6 streams return in my single pod application which is with 1GB memory on it.
Out of these 6 pods 2 streams written to process the bulk loads (50-100K messages with each message of size around 10 KB)

Our NiFi workflow publishes around 50K to 110K messages within 3-4 mins, and using  `BulkStreams` I'm trying to read all messages but after reading 20K - 30K records stream stops reading messages from topic. Kafka team confirmed all messages have been consumed by same consumer group (there is no other consumer in my consumer group, or there is no other consumer group active at this point)

Please check my code details here.

libs -

```
springBootVersion=2.5.12
springCloudVersion=3.0.3
// Kafka
implementation group: "org.springframework.kafka", name: "spring-kafka", version: "2.8.2"
implementation group: "org.apache.kafka", name: "kafka-streams", version: "2.7.1"
implementation group: "org.apache.kafka", name: "kafka-clients", version: "2.7.1"
implementation group: "org.apache.kafka", name: "kafka-streams-test-utils", version: "2.7.1"
```

Here is my code -

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class BulkStreams extends ConsumerStreams {
    @Value("${kafka.topic}")
    private String kafkaTopic;
    @Value("${application.env}")
    private String environment;
    @Value("${applicationId}")
    private String applicationId;
    @Value("${brokers}")
    private String kafkaServers;
    @Value("${javax.net.ssl.trustStore}")
    private String sslTrustStore;
    @Value("${javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword}")
    private String sslTrustStorePassword;
    @Value("${connect.ssl.keystore.location}")
    private String sslKeystoreLocation;
    @Value("${connect.ssl.keystore.password}")
    private String sslKeystorePassword;
    @Value("${connect.ssl.key.password}")
    private String sslKeyPassword;
    @Value("${ssl.protocol}")
    private String sslProtocol;
    @Value("${security.protocol}")
    private String securityProtocol;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(
                getStreamsBuilder().build(),
                getKafkaConsumerBuilderProperties(
                        applicationId,
                        kafkaServers,
                        "30000",
                        "0",
                        securityProtocol,
                        sslProtocol,
                        sslTrustStore,
                        sslTrustStorePassword,
                        sslKeystoreLocation,
                        sslKeystorePassword,
                        sslKeyPassword,
                        environment));
        try {
            streams.start();
            log.info("Started streams for topic {}", kafkaTopic);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log.error("Failed to start streams instance on topic {}. Details: {}", kafkaTopic, t);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void close() {
          }
    }

    public StreamsBuilder getStreamsBuilder() {

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream(kafkaTopic);

        source.transform(() -> new Transformer<String, String, KeyValue<Object, Object>>() {
            private ProcessorContext context;

            @Override
            public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            public KeyValue<Object, Object> transform(String key, String value) {

                String traceId = String.format("%s | %s", kafkaTopic, LocalDateTime.now());
                try {
                    log.info("message from kafkaTopic= {} for feeds, key= {}, value= {}", kafkaTopic, key, value);

                    //logic to persist data in DB
    
                    return new KeyValue<>(key, value);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    log.error("Exception in reading feed: {}, key={}, value: {}", exception, key, value);
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void close() {

            }
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Properties set

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ConsumerStreams {

    @Autowired
    MetricRegistration metricRegistration;

    Properties getKafkaConsumerBuilderProperties(String applicationId,
                                                 String kafkaServers,
                                                 String commitIntervalMsConfig,
                                                 String cacheMaxBytesBuffering,
                                                 String securityProtocol,
                                                 String sslProtocol,
                                                 String sslTrustStore,
                                                 String sslTrustStorePassword,
                                                 String sslKeystoreLocation,
                                                 String sslKeystorePassword,
                                                 String sslKeyPassword,
                                                 String environment) {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, commitIntervalMsConfig); //30000
        props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, cacheMaxBytesBuffering); //0
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        //new
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 100);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 500000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);

        if (!(environment.equals("local") || environment.equals("dev") || environment.equals("sft"))) {
            props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, securityProtocol);
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, sslProtocol);
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, sslTrustStore);
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, sslTrustStorePassword);
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, sslKeystoreLocation);
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, sslKeystorePassword);
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, sslKeyPassword);
        }

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return props;
    }

    protected void logStream(String key, String value, String topic, MetricNames metric){
        log.debug("message from kafkaTopic={}, key={}, message={} ",
                  topic,
                  key,
                  value);
        metricRegistration.incrementCounter(metric.getName() + Constants.MESSAGE_CONSUMED_COUNTER);
    };

}
```

I tried several ways -

- Updated the spring and kafka lib versions to -

```
springBootVersion=2.6.6
springCloudVersion=3.1.0
// Kafka
implementation group: "org.springframework.kafka", name: "spring-kafka", version: "2.8.7"
implementation group: "org.apache.kafka", name: "kafka-streams", version: "3.0.0"
implementation group: "org.apache.kafka", name: "kafka-clients", version: "3.0.0"
implementation group: "org.apache.kafka", name: "kafka-streams-test-utils", version: "3.0.0"
```

- Tried with lowering the COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG to 1000 (1 sec) (default was 3 sec)
- Trued with lowering the COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG to 1000 (1 sec) and increasing the CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG 10MB to 100MB (default was 0)
- Later reverted COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG to 3000 (3 sec) and CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG to 0 and added below new properties -

```
       //new
       props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 300);
       props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 500000);
       props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
```

Followed - https://medium.com/bakdata/solving-my-weird-kafka-rebalancing-problems-c05e99535435

I tried MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG with 100, 200 and 300 it helped me to increased my consumption from 20K to 30K but that's it.

*I have few observations while trying these options -*

- No errors found in logs, stream was starting successfully, I was able to get all messages for < 50K files.
- Stream was consuming messages around 3-4 mins (may be the same time as publishing time)
- POD CPU utilization was around 40-50% while message consumption later it was coming down to 20%
- There were no big memory utilization spike but overall utilization was in range of 700-800 MB.

I think I have tried enough from my end, please suggest if I'm missing anything.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure:  There is no place in the code where exceptions are not logged correctly?

Comment: Why not use Spring Cloud Stream Binder?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thanks for  checking. Code is very straight forward, there is no place where I have missed logging the exceptions and it not that code is failing, it just not work in case of higer number of messages.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'll check for Spring Cloud Stream Binder.

Comment: Could it be because the close() method is not closing the transformer?

Comment: @Rickky13 Thanks for checking. `close()` method is there in code, I missed to post here. I have updated the post now.